# Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load WSDL URL

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using SOAP API Web Services,

By using this i am getting below error:

```
Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 
'https://paas.cloud.clickandpledge.com/paymentservice.svc?wsdl' :
Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/nati9630/public_html/testsoap.php 
on line 4
```

**PHP Code:**

```
 $connect = array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'trace' => 1,
                  'exceptions' => 0, 
                  'verify_peer' => false,
                  'verify_peer_name'  => false);
        $client = new SoapClient('https://paas.cloud.clickandpledge.com/
                paymentservice.svc?wsdl', $connect);
        $soapParams = array('');         
        $response = $client->Operation($soapParams);

        print_r($response);
```